# Canonical way to get static asset version

Tags: magento2

I can write a function easily enough to `file_get_contents('pub/static/deployed_version.txt')`, but I'm curious, is there an M2 class that provides this behavior already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Deployment\Version\Storage\File

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\View\Deployment\Version\Storage\File $versionSystem,
    ...
) {
    $this->versionSystem = $versionSystem;
}
```

> $content = $this->versionSystem->load();